# Как поймать событие автозаполнения формы в Chrome angular2

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, angular2

У меня есть форма из 2 полей и кнопки. У кнопки стоит `[disabled]="!canGo()"`. Когда открывается страница с формой, браузер подставляет туда сохраненные данные. Проблема в том, что в хроме эта кнопка не становится активной до тех пор, пока не ткнешь мышкой в любое место на странице. В фаерфоксе такой проблемы нет — после автозаполнения кнопка становится активной. Как победить хром?

Answer (score 1):

только что столкнулся с такой же проблемой, и пока что ничего кроме как использовать setInterval(), и бегать кругами по форме проверяя её значене в голову не приходит, но кажется мне что это решение так себе, мож кто чё лучше посоветует

Comment: К сожалению такое решение не походит, выглядит как костыль

Comment: Ваш ответ не является аргументированным и конкретным ответом на поставленный вопрос. Пользуйтесь комментариями, если вы хотите уточнить или посоветовать.

Comment: @0xdb Почему же? это решение вполне пригодно для использования.

Comment: Возможно, но как вы описываете - "мож кто чё лучше посоветует". Напишите позитивно - "я использую как воркароунд...так-и-сяк... и это работает потому, что... ".

Comment: @0xdb я не писал "мож кто чё лучше посоветует"

Comment: @A50  Извините, проглядел. Если я комментирую без @, то я обращаюсь автоматически к автору вопроса или ответа, т.е. в данном случае не к Вам.

Answer (score -1):

у меня проблема была такова когда пользователь вводит данные формы после каждого введенного символа срабатывала функция валидацыи формы, но когда браузер светил подсазку чтобы самому дозаполнить данный input, естественно функцыя валидацыи не срабатывала и поле светилось как не правильно заполненое.В итоге долго мучался а ответ оказался как всегда простым))) повесил дополнительный обработчик, с событием input и как оказалось в данном случае оно срабатывет при автозаполнении))) ВУАЛЯ!!!

$("#new_login").on('input', function(){
         alert('Содержимое поля изменилось');
});

Comment: нормальный ответ, какая разница jquery или нет, тут вам говорят - "используйте событие input" как бы ставить минус из-за собственного хейтерства чего либо весьма странно

Answer (score -2):

```
$("#someInput").on('input', function(){
         alert('Содержимое поля изменилось');
});
```

Comment: о нет, только не жквери.

Comment: используй то же событие в чистом js кто тебе мешает? Вот тебе весь список событий смотри, читай, ищи что нужно, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: никто не мешает. В ангуляре итак есть все эти события у инпута, но они в хроме срабатывают после того как мышкой ткнешь на страницу. По поводу жквери, удивлен что 2 ответа именно с ним. Пора уже выкинуть эту библиотеку.

Comment: @АлександрЛычик, всё равно не поможет это событие.